# Captura ErrorCode con FireDAC y Delphi

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Cordial saludo,

Tengo Delphi 10.3 y trabajo con Firebird 3.0, me gustaria saber como puedo capturar el mensaje de error que da Firebird con los componentes FIREDAC, antes con los componentes FIBPlus podia hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
if (E is EFIBError) then
  case EFIBError(E).IBErrorCode of
    335544347 : scMessageDlg('Los campos CONCEPTO, VALOR Y TIPO son obligatorios',mtError,[mbOk],0);
  end;
  Action := daAbort;
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

FireDac tiene una serie de clases de excepciones que son específicas para cada Driver y puedes tirar de ella para obtener información específica del error.

En el caso de Firebird, que comparte código con el driver de Interbase, debes incluir la unidad `FireDAC.Phys.IBWrapper` en la cláusula `uses` de tu unidad. Esta declara la clase `EIBNativeException`, que es la que se eleva cuándo Firebird responde con un error y podrías replicar lo que tienes en el código de ejemplo así:

```
if (E is EIBNativeException) then
  case EIBNativeException(E).ErrorCode of
    335544347 : scMessageDlg('Los campos CONCEPTO, VALOR Y TIPO son obligatorios',mtError,[mbOk],0);
  end;
  Action := daAbort;
```

De manera un poco más general, puedes ver la información de los errores que trae, por ejemplo así:

```
  except
    on E:EIBNativeException do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Error de IB/FB');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Error code: ' + E.ErrorCode.ToString);
      for I := 0 to E.ErrorCount - 1 do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Format(I.ToString + ' Exception  code: %d, SQLCode: %d, ErrClass: %d, ErrCode: %d, SQLState: %s, ErrorCode: %d, Kind: %d, Level: %d, Message: %s '
          , [  E.Errors[I].ExceptionCode
             , E.Errors[I].SQLCode
             , E.Errors[I].ErrClass
             , E.Errors[I].ErrCode
             , E.Errors[I].SQLState {s}
             , E.Errors[I].ErrorCode
             , Integer(E.Errors[I].Kind)
             , E.Errors[I].Level
             , E.Errors[I].Message {s}
        ]));
      end;
    end;
```